# How to check a string that contains more than one pattern and replace that pattern

Tags: java

I tried to check a string that contains some patterns, and I want to replace that pattern. I stored that pattern in an ArrayList. Here is what I've done:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> pattern = new ArrayList<String>();
    pattern.add("pattern1");
    pattern.add("pattern2");
    pattern.add("pattern3");
    pattern.add("pattern4");
    pattern.add("pattern10");
    pattern.add("pattern20");

    ArrayList<String> replace = new ArrayList<String>();
    replace.add("(*pattern1*)");
    replace.add("(*pattern2*)");
    replace.add("(*pattern3*)");
    replace.add("(*pattern4*)");
    replace.add("(*pattern10*)");
    replace.add("(*pattern20*)");

    String sentence = "some sentence pattern1 and pattern10 or pattern20";

    for(int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++){
        if(sentence.contains(pattern.get(i))){
            sentence = sentence.replace(pattern.get(i), replace.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

The code above not replace all my pattern. The result is

```
some sentence (*pattern1*) and (*pattern1*)0 or (*pattern2*)0
```

The result is not what I expected. I expect something like this

```
some sentence (*pattern1*) and (*pattern10*) or (*pattern20*)
```

Can someone help me to check the string with all the pattern and than replace the pattern?

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you told it to. If you want different results, you'll need to define more detailed patterns, probably using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for `pattern10` before `pattern1`, as `pattern1` will also change `pattern10`...

In this solution you need to verify than no target pattern (what you replace with) contain source pattern (what you replace), otherwise some target patterns will also be changed.

Another solution is to add space at the end of each String, but then you need to (temporary) add another space at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks @BobTheBuilder So what I need to do, is reverse the loop when I tried to check if the sentence is contains the pattern?

Comment: You should make sure you check the strings in the right order. The code does just as you program it too...

Comment: thanks man, it works if I add space after all the String.. thank you

Comment: That still won't work, because `pattern1` is contained in `(*pattern10*)`. The results will be even worse.

Comment: @shmosel why? adding spaces will cause them to be different.

Comment: I was referring to the ordering solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that with digit matching and grouping:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final String sentence = "some sentence pattern1 and pattern10 or pattern20";
    System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("pattern([\\d]*)", "(*pattern$1*)"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your for loop to this, and your program will work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++){
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern.get(i)+"(?:\\W|$)");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(sentence);
    if(m.find()){
        sentence = sentence.replaceAll(m.group(), replace.get(i));
    }
}
```